# Is splitting a wire off of a single 5V pin the same as using two 5V pins?

Tags: power, pi-zero-w, lcd

In other words, is two 5V pins plugged into two pins on another device (say a 16x2 LCD display) different or the same as using one 5V pin on the pi and splitting it to two pins on the LCD?

For more context, I'm adapting this breadboard diagram to a Raspberry Pi Zero W. On the breadboard all the 5V connections are in parallel with a single 5V pin, but in my implementation it is easier to use two different pins (I'm plugging pin-to-pin with jumper cables).

[image]

Comment: 5V is 5V - it is unclear exactly what you are asking. You should clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is it the same 5V or two different 5Vs? Like does it add to make 10V?

Comment: They are all connected together on the Pi. **Voltages ARE NOT additive**. Additional pins are only provided for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

> On the breadboard all the 5V connections are in series with a single 5V pin

No they're not, they are in parallel.

They were using same 5v source but the current draw will be shared by those connected components.

You can just try it with Pi Zero.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say parallel. I corrected it.